# Heroku: Ruby system() commands on java target using multipack

Tags: git, heroku, github, buildpack

On Heroku I want to do

java_controller.rb:

```
system("java hello");
```

I tried the multipack solution with

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

.buildpacks

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java.git
```

And I keep getting

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app

when I do a git push heroku master.

This seems like it is due to `git clone` in multipack compile causing
error: The requested URL returned error: 400 while accessing https://...
git --version is 1.7.0

Comment: Hey, I;m getting the same error, what did you do?

Comment: Its your git client that is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that app not recognise as java or ruby app, first see which build pack failed (by using only one of them and see if it's work).

For ruby app your app must have Gemfile
For java app you app must have pom.xml file